# best way to find the row of dictionary contain the list item python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have list of name's and I have a `dataframe` of that names and barcode and ... 
Now I want to check the `dataframe` name column if in `name_list` put the `barcode` of that `name` into new `dataframe` 
 I use this code but It's soo slow

```
import pandas as pd

orgDF = pd.read_excel('./orgData.xlsx')
allCats = pd.read_excel('./ALLCat.xlsx')
```

this is the `orgDF` dataframe

```
id  Barcode         name        Brand
1   6261959402398   aaaaa        A
2   6261959402398   bbbbb        B
3   6261959402398   ccccc        C
4   6261959402398   ddddd        D
```

and this is a `allCats_name`

```
aaaa
bbbb
cccc
```

this is the code for make `dataframe` of that list

```
allCats_name = allCats.name.tolist()
org_name = orgDF.name.tolist()
org_barcode = orgDF.Barcode.tolist()
org_brand = orgDF.Brand.tolist()

list_name = []
list_barcode = []
list_brand = []


for k in range(len(org_name)):
    if org_name[k] in allCats_name:
        list_name.append(allCats_name[allCats_name.index(org_name[k])])
        list_barcode.append(org_barcode[k])
        list_brand.append(org_brand[k])
```

then I make `dataframe` of that `list's`, but its soooooo slow

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the `orgDF` and `allCats` DataFrames? This will help make your question reproducible

Comment: @DerekO I added the sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose the following dataframes:

```
>>> orgDF
   name BarCode   Brand
0  cat1     001  brand1
1  cat2     010  brand2
2  cat3     100  brand3

>>> allCats
   name
0  cat1
1  cat3
```

Do you expect this result?

```
>>> pd.merge(orgDF, allCats, on='name')
   name BarCode   Brand
0  cat1     001  brand1
1  cat3     100  brand3
```

To remove duplicated values:

```
newDF = pd.merge(orgDF, allCats, on='name').drop_duplicates('name', keep='first')
```

Comment: this is good way but I got this after run your code
orgDF len   154541
allCats len 110418
newDF len     121201

Comment: What do you expect? `len(newDF) == len(orgDF)`? If yes use `newDF.drop_duplicates('name', keep='first')`. I will update my code based on your answer.